# Why does Apache require Other's execute permission on folder

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, centos, cpanel

I have a webapp setup on cPanel/Apache/CentOS
If I set the permission of directories under document root to 755, it works OK. However, if I change any directory permission to 754 (revoke execute permission from OTHER group), the web server refuses to serve any file under the folder, resulting in `404 not found` error.

Apache is running as the file owner, so why does it bother to care about the OTHER's execute permission?

Answer (score 0):

> Apache is running as the file owner, so why does it bother to care about the OTHER's execute permission?

Are you sure about that? Apache is almost never configured this way, outside of exotic setups like [mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/). The web server is usually configured to run as a separate user, often as `www-data`, `httpd`, or `nobody`. These users are not members of your group, so they rely on the "other" privilege mask.

Depending on your site configuration, you might be able to add an access control list to the document root to explicitly allow the web server user, or chgrp your document root to a group shared with the web server to use group privileges instead. (Or you might not. No guarantees.)

Comment: I'm sure of that, because I had configure it that way. I also checked with exec('whoami') to be sure about the current process' owner.

Comment: @Napoleon That doesn't confirm anything. PHP can, and often does, run as a separate user from the web server.